# Webrtc Capture Desktop Audio Without using vb-audio cable driver for Native Windows

Tags: c#, audio, webrtc, driver

I'm writing a native WebRTC app on Windows and I'm trying to set WebRTC to trying to capture desktop audio for input instead of the default microphone.

I've been doing research on this and besides some patch from for the WebRTC code, i don't seem to see any high-level way of doing this when adding audio tracks to the stream or creating the peer connection. Create a custom audio module need some guidance how to do it.

We are using virtual audio cable driver that is set to default and remote end receives the audio but for commercial purpose we cannot use this driver.
Can someone please guide me how can i eliminate virtual audio driver all together or free virtual audio driver that can be used for commercial purpose.

Is there any other proper way of doing this that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a hard topic, webrtc it's prepared for conference and the important audio it's from the mic. Some directions: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer#desktopcapturer -> https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/atom/browser/api/atom_api_desktop_capturer.cc

Comment: we want something native windows than web(electron or nwjs). Suprised no one in webrtc community had this issue.